# codeigniter form set value?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I must know..

is

`$this->form_validation->set_value('first_name')`

the same as

```
$this->input->post('first_name')
```

?

They both seem to get the input value. Is the first one more secure if I'm validating inputs?

Comment: i think 2nd one is better that 1st one ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set_value()` is used to re-populate a form once it has failed validation. There is no additional filtering on it, so you should use `$this->input->post()` if you have no need to pass the value back to the form.

Comment: I have a trim on the input, when i use set_value('email'), the re-populated field is trimmed. so i don't think set_value() has no filter effect.

Answer (score 7):

`set_value()` can return a default value if one is set in the second parameter, and will not return anything if the field was not validated with the Form Validation library, whereas `$this->input->post()` will return the `$_POST` value even if the field was not processed by the validation lib.

Both functions will return the modified value if "prep" rules have been run on the input.

When you want to read a post value, just use `$this->input->post()`, the `set_value()` type functions like `set_select()` and `set_checkbox()` will actually return something like `selected="selected"` rather than the actual input value, so this won't work for checkboxes, radios, and selects.

Comment: `set_value()` also behaves differently with array $_POST values too. In short - it's used to repopulate a form and nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're referring to this:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo set_value('quantity', '0'); ?>" size="50" />
```

Which in this case `set_value` is just repopulating the field on validation error. This:

```
$this->input->post('first_name');
```

Is just getting the `$_POST` value of `first_name`.

Answer (score 2):

With the previous validation library the`validation->first_name` and `input->post(‘first_name’)` were interchangeable but the new library doesn’t alters the post values anymore.